# Find Kernel of a group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi: \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ be a group homomorphism such that $\phi ((1,0))=-2$ and $\phi ((0,1))=7$. Find $\ker(\phi)$.

I know that $\phi ((a,b))=-2a+7b$. In order to find the $\ker(\phi)$, it must happen that $-2a+7b=0$, so, $2a=7b$. But I don't know how to proceed, I am stuck at this point. An intuitive response is that $\ker(\phi)=2\Bbb Z \times 7\Bbb Z$, but I am not sure.

I really appreciate any hint.

Comment: Try $(a,b)=k(7,2) $ with $k\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: Did you mean $\phi((0,1))=7$?

Comment: If $2a=7b$, then $2\mid 7b$, but $\gcd(2,7)=1$, so $2\mid b$. Similarly with $7\mid 2a$.

Comment: Your answer is a subgroup of $7 \mathbb{Z} \times 2 \mathbb{Z}$ If it helps you, use linear algebra reasoning (replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$). You can show that your kernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and is actually the image of $n \mapsto (7n, 2n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us continue your reasoning: Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$
$$\begin{align*}
(a,b) \in \ker \phi & \iff -2a + 7b = 0 \iff 2a = 7b 
\end{align*}$$
But Gauss theorem tells you that $2|7b \implies 2 |b$, dually $7|2a \implies 7 | a$, so
$$\begin{align*}
(a,b) \in \ker \phi & \iff \exists n,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \, 7n = a, \, 2m = b, \, 2a = 7b \\
&\iff \exists n,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \, 7n = a, \, 2m = b, \, 2\cdot 7n = 7\cdot 2m\\
&\iff \exists n,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \, 7n = a, \, 2m = b, \, n = m\\
&\iff \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, \, 7n = a, \, 2n = b \\
&\iff (a,b) \in \operatorname{range} (n \mapsto (7n,2n))
\end{align*}$$

In category theory we would say that the kernel of $\phi$ is $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ defined by $f(1) = (7,2)$. But in more practical terms, $\ker \phi = \{(7n,2n), n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

What I meant with my comment regarding linear algebra was how to get from a cartesian equation describing an hyperplane ($2x = 7y$) to the description via a spanning vector (here (7,2)). Also it had to be dimension one!